# Помогите с полиморфизмом Python

Tags: python, полиморфизм

Помогите разобраться с кодом. Никак не могу понять его принцип действия.

```
class Base:

     def __init__(self,N):
          self.numb = N

     def out(self):
         self.numb /= 2 
         print (self.numb)

class Subclass(Base):

     def out(self):
          print ("----")
          Base.out(self)
          print ("----")

i = 0

while i < 10:
     if 4 < i < 7:
          obj = Subclass(i)
     else:
          obj = Base(i)
     i += 1
     obj.out()

0
0
1
1
2
----
2
----
----
3
----
3
4
4
```

Какой принцип вывода принт? почему только до 4 выводит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите: мы имеем два класса, имеющих аналогичный интерфейс, в данном случае метод out. Полиморфизм заключается в том, что мы можем взаимодействовать с разными классами посредством одного интерфейса. 
Если класс Base в методе out просто выводит numb/2 то Subclass выведет тоже самое обрамлённое знаками ----
Полиморфизм позволяет нам в одном цикле взаимодействовать с объектами обоих классов, при этом каждый из них ведёт себя по своему.

Тут всё просто, только вот пример наверное не жизненный, оттого и не понятно. Приведу пример применения полиморфизма из жизни: например нам нужно рисовать геометрические фигуры. Имеем абстрактный класс Shape с методом draw:

```
class Shape(object):
    def draw(self):
        print 'рисую фигуру'
```

и классы Triangle и Square, наследники класса Shape:

```
class Triangle(Shape):
    def draw(self):
        print 'рисую треугольник'

class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self):
        print 'рисую квадрат'
```

теперь если у нас есть массив геометрических фигур, то мы можем обрабатывать его одинаково, не зависимо от фигуры, при этом каждый из классов будет рисовать свою фигуру по своему.

Comment: да и как правило для полиморфизма нужен какой-то базовый класс, пусть он даже и не используется напрямую, тогда мы зовём его абстрактным. В моём примере это Shape, в вашем Base

Comment: спасибо, вроде бы понятно, да вот только по моему вопросы не все ясно. как принцип вывода принт? почему только до 4 выводит?

Comment: ну это уже вопрос по работе целочисленного деления)
/ - деление нацело
/= - деление нацело с присвоением
цикл работает при i от 0 до 9:
0/2 = 0
1/2 = 0
2/2 = 1
....
9/2 = 4

Comment: @DenisBoiko: `i < 10`, значит `9` макс. `9/2` на Питоне 2 работает как `9 // 2 == 4`

Comment: @АлексейСтародубцев наследование в Вашем Shape примере не используется. Более того следует предпочитать композицию по умолчанию, по сравнению с наследованием, то есть явно принимать объект и использовать его методы позже. Например, `shutil.copyfileobj(from_file, to_file)` принимает любые объекты с `.read()`, `.write()` методами соответственно и не важно какие классы они наследуют.

Comment: @АлексейСтародубцев слава яйцам! вот оно в чем дело! вот я тугодум) спасибо большое.

Comment: @jfs вот это для меня уже слишком сложно. я только начинаю погружаться в этот чудесный мир)

Comment: @jfs знаю, утиная типизация) Пример слишком краток, однако любой реальный пример с описанным функционалом будет использовать наследование. И я всё же не сторонник таких вольностей, стараюсь как в си подобных языках явно наследовать полиморфные классы, избавляет от тучи проблем при отладке в реальных проектах. Хотя безусловно пример будет работать и без наследования, но я так делать не советую)

Comment: @АлексейСтародубцев так полиморфизм плох? или мне показалось?)

Comment: @DenisBoiko показалось) полиморфизм это азы ООП, как он может быть плохим или хорошим))

Comment: @АлексейСтародубцев: Как раз реальные проекты показали все ужасы злоупотребления наследованием. Как человек, который ООП учил по Java, C++ я симпатизирую, но новичкам сегодня я бы советовал стиль ООП, распространённый в Питоне и усиленный на уровне языка в Go. See [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: @jfs всё может быть. Мне приходилось все тонкости программирования осваивать самому, поэтому возможны неточности.

Answer (score 0):

А какого поведения ты ожидал? Все верно 9 раз вывод. Из них 2 от Subclass. 9/2 == 4 т.к. цельночисленное деление. Замени i = 0 на i = 0.0 и будет все понятно.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.